# Has Devlin a gun or is he bluffing in the last scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, notorious

At the end of Hitchcock's 1946 *Notorious*, Devlin comes to Sebastian's house and rescues Alicia.

After exiting Alicia's room, Devlin threatens to shoot Sebastian and moves one hand closer to the pocket of his suit. Is he bluffing or is there indeed a gun in his pocket?

Considering Hitchcock's attention to details, I suspect the answer should be inferred from the wrinkles of Devlin's pocket.

Comment: Not an answer, because it's nowhere near proof, but IMFdb.org only lists weapons used by Cary Grant for _Gunga Din_, _To Catch A Thief_, and _Charade_.

Comment: Chenmunka, the problem with that (new) tag is: is it for [Notorious (1946)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038787/) or [Notorious (2009)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472198/)

Comment: We have no questions on the later, if we do we would have a new tag [tag:notorious-2009]

Comment: Devlin must indeed have a gun in his pocket. At some point, when walking down the stairs, Sebastian focuses on a threatening associate (timestamp 1:39:33 on the criterion release). At this very moment, an extremely tense Devlin starts taking his hand out of his pocket. This move cannot be meant to bluff Alex who is not watching Devlin.